# asp grid takes two click to sort the data

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, datagrid

I am trying to apply sorting on my grid but its takes two click to sort the data when the page loads. So when page loads.
**First click** on any column) -> No sorting but i see page refreshing

**Second Click** on any column will sort the data.And then it will work for any number of click once page is reloaded again.

Aspx:

```
  <asp:GridView id="SubGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="15" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True" 
            EmptyDataText="There are now submission to display."
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="SubmissionID,Abstract,info,upload,finalized,Submitter"
            OnRowCreated="SubGrid_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="SubGrid_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringTest %>" SelectCommand="sb_Getvelue" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
```

Code Behind:

In code behind i  have two method

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

Protected Sub SubGrid_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
----Some Custom Code to add a extra line on top of the grid.
End Sub

 Protected Sub SubGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As
GridViewRowEventArgs)
----- Some code to add tool tip ----
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions of this issue.Here are my thoughts and logic behind it. Let me know if i am wrong.

Data are bound with SqlDataSource and my SelectCommandType is stored procedure. My stored procedure return the result which is already sorted  by ID(which is my first column). Now what i found is sorting works fine for all the columns at a first try expect "ID" column. Also when i click on column to sort the data  myGrid.SortExpression alwasy return blank value. So i thought grid is already sorted in ASC order by ID through Stored Procedure,when i click on ID column for the first time it again sort the grid in ASC order because its not initialized and sort order is blank.

SO i added this code in the page_load

```
If IsPostBack = False Then

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(myGrid.SortExpression) Then
                myGrid.Sort("SubmissionID", SortDirection.Ascending)
            End If
        End If
```

this will initialize the grid in ASC order when the page loads and now when i click on the ID column for the first time it sort the grid in DESC order. so initializing grid sort order on page load worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in C#, im not sure of the VB equivalent, not sure if it helps but check your postback in your page load.

I had to add in Page_Load

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

Once I added this, subsequent calls worked first click.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what i found out is when i click on First column for sorting for the first time , myGrid.SortExpression is always a blank value. When i click the second time then it gives me the correct value. So i end up setting the  order of my grid in the page load method inside "IsPostBack = False" if statement. which i guess initialize the grid sorting order when the page initially loads. after doing this grid sorting works as it should be. I have added my solutions below.